# Xamarin image fills the page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Hello I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms application.
I have this code and the image fits to page on simulator.
How can I display the image in its original size?

```
var image = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit};
image.Source = "image2.png";
Content = image;
```

Comment: Why do you want to display the Image in it's original size? Why not just set the width and height of the element around?

Comment: When assign a width/height value, it gets error and says : Property and Indexer 'Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.With' cannot be assigned to (it is read-only)

Answer (score 1):

To set the dimensions of an image you can't use the `Width` and `Height` properties. Because the `Width` and `Height` properties are read-only (as the error said).

Try to use the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` properties to set your desired dimension.

Infos from [Xamarin-Developer-Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.WidthRequest/):

> WidthRequest does not immediately change the Bounds of a
>   VisualElement, however setting the WidthRequest will change the result
>   of calls to GetSizeRequest, which will in turn modify the final size
>   the element receives during a layout cycle.

Comment: I have assigned like image.WidthRequest = 20 and image.HeightRequest = 20 but its not changed. Sorry for my English, if I could not got it.

Comment: Hmm.. that should work. Maybe the elements around causing the problems. Can you show me your XAML/C#?

Comment: Its really a blank page. Just a launch page

Comment: Try to put your Image in an `Image` element and surround it with a `StackLayout`. Like in this example: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WorkingWithImages/WorkingWithImages/LocalImagesXaml.xaml

Comment: I think to place the image inside a grid cell. And will assing width value to this cell. So the image will be fit to the cell, rather than page. Can I do this ?

Comment: Sure, you can do almost anything =)